# How to access session created in a blade.php file of Laravel 5.2 in a Controller Method?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I just moved a project from laravel 4.0 to laravel 5.2. Am using a fresh installation of laravel 5.2 as suggested by Taylor. i have successfully transfer all files and web app works fine.

My   challenge is that i have a page called page.blade.php that stores some value in session {{ Session::put('item', $itemSelected) }} base on the user choice and i have a Session::get('item') in my controller to receive this and process some logic.

The session returns null in the controller but when i add     {{Session::get('item')}} in to page.blade.php it display value stored in   $itemSelected. I also observe that session created in controller method can be   access by the page.blade.php but the session created by the page.blade.php can't   be access by the controller method.

Am a little bit confuse here, i need help. This process worked fine in laravel 4.0 before i moved to laravel 5.2

Here is my route

```
route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {  

     Route::get('page', 'Website\PageController@mypage');  

 });
```

Page.blade.php

```
'''''  
   $itemSelected= 'Page 1';  
   {{Session::put('item' , $itemSelected)}}  
   <a   href="{{action('Website\PageController@mypage')}}">Page 1</a>  

......
```

My Controller

```
<?php  

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Website;  

use Illuminate\Http\Request;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;  
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;  
use App\Http\Requests;  
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  
use App\Models\Authuser;  
use View;  
use Redirect;  
use Session;  

return

class PageController extends Controller {  

    public function mypage()  
    {
       ...  
        $selectedPage = Session::get('item');  //this suppose to return "Page 1" but returns null
      ....  
    }
}
```

Comment: is it $itemSelcted or $itemSelected?

Comment: If you are using `Session` in the views, the value set will be available in controllers only in the next request.

Answer (score 1):

I can't call this an answer to this issue but another way to get the job done.

From the view page.blade.php, I pass the value $itemSelected as a $_GET variable on a url. When link is clicked the controller picks the value from the request with Input::get('item'). Then persist the return value from request into Session (Session::put('item',$itemSelected). This got the task done.

Answer (score 0):

Because it hasn't been set yet, you set it in the view, which is created after you run that line. I am guessing that is what the '...' implies.